# Use of "Asynchronously"

Tags: word-usage

What conjunction is used with the word "asynchronously" 
A is running asynchronously *[conjunction]* B

I am aware asynchronous is running at the same time  **as**  something else 
However, something occurs  **with**  something else 

So what conjunction or otherwise, joins asynchronously and a noun:
A is running asynchronously *with* B 
A is running asynchronously, *as is* B 
A is running asynchronously *parallel to* B 
Or otherwise?


 *I may be using the word conjunction wrongly, if so, I am sorry :P*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you were talking about a bus and a ferry service.

If they were running synchronously, if one of the services were running late, then the other would wait in order to pick up the first's passengers.

Asynchronously they wouldn't wait for each other.

In this case - describing the relationship between the two, you would use *with*.

> The bus service runs synchronously with the ferry service, if the bus is running late, the ferry will wait for you.
>
> The bus service runs asynchronously with the ferry service, if the bus is running late you may miss your ferry.